# How can I set YouTube's default volume in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

Up until yesterday, I set a YouTube video’ss volume to 25%, and YouTube remembered that between videos.

Yesterday, I cleared YouTube’s cache and it stopped remembering the default volume setting. Now every time I open a new YouTube video, it defaults to 100% volume and I have to manually turn it down.

How can I get YouTube to remember my default volume setting again? I have cookies enabled but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: This [article](https://ghacks.net/2013/10/12/set-fix-video-volume-youtube/) from 2014 says that this occurs when you disallow third-party cookies in Chrome. If that's your case, try adding YouTube to the cookies exceptions list. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @harrymc I already did this, it didn't help.

Comment: Please add more details, i.e., if you are using software that runs in the background to remove temporary files, if you are using extensions, if you are using a Google consumer account (typically, the primary email address has `@gmail.com`) or if you use a managed account (from school, work, etc.).

Comment: @Wicket I'm not using any such background software, and I'm using a gmail account.

Answer (score 1):

I restarted my PC and when I reopened Chrome afterwards, the problem had fixed itself.